# How to compile PJSIP for Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, voip, pjsip

I'm trying to compile PJSIP for Android. I follow official tutorial from this site: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android.
Unfortunately when I execute command "make dep" I get this error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Samples.mak dependmake[2]: Nothing to be done for `depend'.
```

My steps:

- I cloned repo from svn. Also tried release package.
- I added config_site.h. Exactly the same as in tutorial.
- Android NDK export is defined in bash_profile.
- Execution of ./configure-android goes without any problems.

I'm using MacOS for building. I also tried on Ubuntu but I get the same error...

In MacOS I also have SWIG installed throught brew package manager.

Any ideas why I get this error? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to make it work. You have to modify Makefile in (project_root)/pjsip-apps/build and move line:

```
$(MAKE) -f Samples.mak $@
```

to saparate section without "depend":

```
clean realclean:
    $(MAKE) -f Samples.mak $@
```